# Cannot update Microsoft Office Word 2011 to 14.2.3 on OSX

Tags: macos, ms-office, macbook-pro, software-update

I just purchased Microsoft Office 2011 for MAC and installed it on my rMBP OSX 10.8.2 running Mountain Lion. The installed version from purchase is 14.2.0. I tried installing  14.2.3 but it failed due to a specific file that was not found :

```
Office 14.2.3 can't be installed on this disk.
A version of the software required to install this update was not found on this volume.
```

---

So I went to the site and downloaded 14.2.1, but that didn't install either with the same message. Also tried 14.2.2, but still the same error.

I want to add that the actual installation failed (tried twice), however Office 2011 appeared in the application folders and Word works fine.

Not sure what can be causing this, any idea ?

Comment: I encounter the same problem. May I know after the cleanup and re-installation, do you need to register the product key again?

Comment: @IvanH I cannot remember exactly, but a `clean` uninstallation did prompt me to enter the product key again. If you did not delete every single file related to MS, then the product key might still be registered and you may not need to re-enter it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue once. I ended up backing up my data via Time Machine (for a get out of jail card) and then removing Office in it's entirety, rebooted my Macbook Pro, and then proceeded to reinstall Office 2011. Once I had the Office suite reinstalled the software  allowed me to apply all subsequent updates without issue. This worked for my particular instances / issue, results may vary depending on software environment.

Comment: Surely there should be an easier way to fix this ?!

Comment: There may possibly be but when I was searching for a solution I did not find one. The OSX version of Office does not have a built in repair function as does the Windows version of Office. This may be because its not a common issue. Strictly a theory mind you.

Comment: How did you remove office 2011 ? I tried many various ways on the internet as well as the official Microsoft website but installation always fails (yet word runs fine), and any subsequent updates completely fail to install.

Comment: I used AppCleaner which you can download from here: (http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/). It worked well for my particular issue anyway.

Comment: I did use AppCleaner .. I think my issue is deeper unforutantely ... Did you just click on the Word app through AppCleaner and thats it ?

Comment: Yep, that's all I did. My process may be ineffective if you have further underlying issues.

Comment: May I ask what was the use of the Time Machine backup if all you did was use AppCleaner to remove office ?

Comment: Just to backup my important Word and Excel documents in case anything went bad on me.

Comment: So you actually formatted your mac to fix the issue ?

Comment: I backed up my documents. I then used APP cleaner to remove office. Rebooted. Then I reinstalled office. My issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that problem is based on the initial installation having failed, and that the only way to fix it would be to forcibly remove all of your Office-related 'receipts' and try again.

Note: THIS IS POTENTIALLY DANGEROUS AND I CANNOT PROMISE THAT IT WILL SOLVE THE PROBLEM. That being said, I tried it on my 'test system' and it appeared to work. FOR ME. YMMV.

1) Move all of your 'com.microsoft' receipts to the Desktop:

```
sudo mv -vf /private/var/db/receipts/com.microsoft.* ~/Desktop/
```

2) Download and reinstall Microsoft Office 2011.

Note that I have written a shell script to help facilitate this. You can find it at https://github.com/tjluoma/office2011/blob/master/office2011.sh

Assuming you are comfortable with the Terminal.app, you can use the script like this:

```
cd ~/Downloads/

curl --location --remote-name https://raw.github.com/tjluoma/office2011/master/office2011.sh

chmod 755 office2011.sh

./office2011.sh
```

That will download the official DMGs from Microsoft and use the official command-line package installer from Apple. Which means that it will *not* install if it finds matching receipts at `/private/var/db/receipts/com.microsoft.*`

I strongly encourage you to ONLY try this IF you have a verified backup of your enter boot drive (SuperDuper or CarbonCopyCloner, not just TimeMachine).

Comment: Thank you for replying. Why do I need to backup ? Is there a chance for this to corrupt my drive ?

Comment: Well, if you move them to the Desktop, you should be able to move them back, but anytime you're tinkering around under the surface it is a good idea to have a backup just in case. A typo in the Terminal can be a bad thing. 99 times out of 100, or more, you'll have no problem, but better to be prepared and not need it than wish you had taken a few minutes to update your SuperDuper clone beforehand!

Answer (score 0):

Its easy. Rename the folder where office resides back to Microsoft Office 2011. You probably changed it before hence it cannot find.